# Resources for learning Rails 3 through a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I recently finished my Rails app following `Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial Book`. I have been toying around with the app by adding extra features such as Photo uploads, Twitter-user sign-in etc etc. I was wondering whether there are in another Rails resources out there that use Hartl's project-based approach towards learning.

I was directed towards `Rails for Zombies` and found it to be very limited and big step back after Hartl. I was suggested `Rails 3 in Action by Ryan Bigg and Yehuda Katz.`

Would be grateful if you any of you could provide me with some `project-based learning` resources for Rails.

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I was in the same situation few months back.** In adition to finishing Hartls tutorial, I finished [Peepcode Rails screencast](https://peepcode.com/screencasts) and [Lyndas Tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-on-Rails-tutorials/essential-training/324-2.html), so take a look at those (they cost money but are really good). Also, I read Rails 3 in action - awesome book!

But, I propose an alternative. In adition to reading and watching screencasts **I think it is most important that you take a step away from fixed path tutorials and start to build the app you want to build.** You already know some basics and I think are ready to do this. When I did this, my enthusiasm for Rails and coding exploaded and  gave me a number of positives:

a) **You learn a LOT MORE in a lot shorter timeframe**

b) **You learn to learn from a LOT more resources**, giving you a multiple perspective view on each problem you encounter

c) **You learn to interact with community**. There is a TON of awesome people around, here on SO, on irc chanels... By asking them questions you learn incredible amount from them, more than any tutorial could cover.

d) **You learn to Google.** You learn how to properly search for solutions to your problems, read documentation, read others code... All essential skills.

d) **You learn to think for yourself.** This was a big one for me. All these tutorials, allthough very good and informative, follow and explain only the fixed path. The real world Rails development is much more broader than that, and the sooner you detach yourself from fixed tutorials, the sooner you start learning to research properly and think with your own head

Comment: +1 If you want to learn rails work, after you get the basics down (which you already have now) start a project. Simple as that.

Comment: I was procrastinating/fearing starting a project without having a tutorial to fallback on, but I guess your words have encouraged me to bite the bullet. Thanks a ton for the motivation, oFca!

Comment: Bite the bullet, you won' regret it. Just push through hard times, and don't be afraid to ask questions, even if they make you seem stupid (I embarass myself all the time on irc and here on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Go for Agile web development with rails (Version 4). They have taken a project based approach which explains you working of rails in details. When i started, I first read Agile and then Hartl's tutorial which actually should have been the other way round. Agile explains you most of the things in rails. And also go for rails guides. They are very easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

what about http://rubymonk.com/ and http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0

although it's not something like project-based learning resources but I think it's useful and fun.

Comment: Thanks for resources, Piam! Unfortunately, all of these teach the basics of Ruby, which I am already familiar with. I am looking for Rails resources, which teach through a project and not through a browser

Answer (score 0):

I agree with oFca. I finished the Rails Tutorial and immediately started creating my first app. Much of what is discussed in the tutorial, including associations, is relevant, so I've been bouncing around in the tutorial to figure out how to build parts of my app.

I get into some tricky situations when things don't work, but that's when Google and StackOverflow usually come to the rescue.

Rails is great, the Rails Tutorial is great, and StackOverflow is great!